# Webkit and PyInstaller

Tags: python, webkit, pyinstaller

I created a desktop application in Python using Gtk 3.0, Glade and Webkit. I installed on Windows using the All In One (pygi-aio-3.18.2_rev4-setup.exe) I'm packing everything in a single executable with PyInstaller.

But the Webkit is not being carried along with the exe and when I am opening the program, I get the error :

> Namespace WebKit not availabe

This is because WebKit is not being carried along by PyInstaller. As I've tried adding the dlls and type libraries folder:

> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\gi
>
> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\gnome\lib\girepository-1.0
>
> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\gnome\lib\webkit2gtk-3.0\injected-bundle

**What am I missing? Is there any way to incorporate the Webkit with PyInstaller?**